# socket.io-stream doesn't emit event

Tags: node.js, file-upload, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm trying to create a file upload through socket.io 1.0.4 and the last version of socket.io-stream. Anytime I try to emit `ss(socket).emit('mediaupload', file);` the event is executed on the client but not called on the server side. I don't get any debug or error messages. If I try to emit the event through `socket.emit('mediaupload')` the server gets the event.

Server declaration

```
ss(socket).on('mediaupload', function(stream, data) {
debug('Data:', data);
...
}
```

I don't know what to try anymore.

```
uploadFile: function (fileWithMeta, callback_end, callback_data) {
        var file=fileWithMeta.file;

        var stream = ss.createStream();
        log.log('File to Upload with stream: ', stream);
        ss(socket).emit('mediaupload', file);

        var blobStream = ss.createBlobReadStream(file);
        if (callback_end){
            blobStream.on('end', function(e) {
                callback_end(e);
            });
        }

        if (callback_data){
            var uploadedSize=0;
            blobStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                uploadedSize+=chunk.length;
                callback_data(Math.floor(uploadedSize / file.size * 100), uploadedSize, chunk);
            });
        }
        blobStream.pipe(stream);
    }
```

I read the input file over a angularjs directive.

```
angular.module('oo.util').directive('ooFileReader', ['ooLog', '$parse', function (log, $parse) {
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    //scope: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("change", function (e) {
            $parse(attrs.ooFileReader).assign(scope, e.target.files[0]);                
        });
    }
};}]);
```

part of the template

```
 <input name="fileupload" type="file" oo-file-reader="fileupload" multiple>
```

Functioncall: uploadFile is called with the variavle $scope.fileupload

```
$scope.uploadFile=function(file){
    log.log('Add File: ', file);
    websocket.uploadFile(file, function(){
        log.log('Upload Finished!');
    }, function(percentUploaded){
        log.log('Uploading: ' + percentUploaded + '%');
    });
};
```

Comment: I've just tried to run the example code (a bit modified) from [NPM site](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io-stream), and it works fine with Socket.IO 1.0.4 and latest Socket.IO-stream. Can you show your full code?

Comment: I added the code to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

After including the socket.io-stream script on the client as described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream):

```
cp node_modules/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js somewhere/public/
```

you can do something like the following:

```
function(file){
  var stream = ss.createStream();
  ss(socket).emit("stream", stream, {},function(){})
  ss.createBlobReadStream(file).pipe(stream)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream#browser), you have to emit `stream`, not `file`.

Try to replace

```
ss(socket).emit('mediaupload', file);
```

with

```
ss(socket).emit('mediaupload', stream);
```